# R sum values by substring position (no columns)

Tags: r

I have a task to sum multiple flags in 400 b long file (500K rows), my input is .txt file.
I know that I can use colSums, but I do not want to load data with columns, as it's to dynamic, so if I need  let say to sum value like substring(d,12,13), d,16,16. ho to to do this in smart way?  So fare I got something like below,  I use writeLInes for input just for clean test, main part is not working where ##
Tx all

```
    dd <- c('Charly 010101010101010101010','Mike   011111111111113111111','Zulu   010101010101010101010')
    dd
    writeLines(dd, "IN.txt")

    d <- readLines("IN.txt")
    d
    cl <- c('C1','C2')       ## col names

    d1 <-  ## !!!
         c( sum(as.numeric(substring(d,12,13))),
            sum(as.numeric(substring(d,16,16)))
          )
    d1

    out <- data.frame(cl,d1)
    write.csv("Out.csv", out")

###  desired output    *** updated 6/12 1pm EST
C1  C2
13   1
```

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: It's unlcear what you are asking. Aside from the syntax error at `d1 < ###!!!` what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Tx guys, sorry, lost my edits, now corrected.

Comment: In your desired output, don't you want C1 to be 13, not 12?

Comment: G5, you're correct 13 , 1 Tx